# EditText causes StackOverflowError on older devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, stack-overflow

I am using a third party tool to create a `TableView` similar to iPhone, [you can see it here](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview).

I have done a good bit of editing of this package, and have added the ability for a row to have an EditText. I tested it on different devices and it works great. Now the issue I am having is, if I have this UITableView inside a nested layout and give a row an edit text, when the user clicks the EditText on some older devices, it causes a stackoverflow.

This is within a fragment. The Structure looks like this

(1)                (2)               (3)               (4)
RelativeLayout -> RelativeLayout -> RelativeLayout -> ScrollLayout -> UITableView

There is bit of background behind this but long story short I need all these layouts, so removing one of them is not an option. This is frustrating as if I remove one of the RelativeLayouts, the app does not crash.

The android UITableView is also set up using several LinearLayouts. Ideally it would be great if I could set LinearLayout to be able to scroll, that way I could remove the ScrollLayout and the issue would be gone, but sadly I don't believe that is possible.

The error I am getting is

```
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2758)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:2759)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView$HandleView.isPositionVisible(TextView.java:8228)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView$HandleView.moveTo(TextView.java:8245)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView$HandleView.positionAtCursor(TextView.java:8340)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView$InsertionPointCursorController.updatePosition(TextView.java:8401)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView.updateCursorControllerPositions(TextView.java:4292)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4281)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7093)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1421)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
06-13 07:42:23.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.view.Vi
```

I have tested this on many newer devices, Nexus, HTC etc and there is no issue. However when I tested this on an older device, the Sony Ericson Mini Pro 2 this error happens. I want to ensure this app does not crash on older devices, currently app supports 2.3.3+

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this recursive call is happening which is causing older devices to crash? And is there anyway to prevent this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you have is too deep for some of the devices out there to handle. You have 4 layouts from what you posted(only from the fragment? if yes, then you also have layouts from the activity) + the `UITableView`. Now I don't know what changes did you made but from a quick look in the code for the `UITableView` is not very efficient. `UITableView` extends `LinearLayout` only to inflate another layout as its content which consists of a `LinearLayout` wrapping another `Linearlayout`. So the `UITableView` adds another three extra layouts not mentioning its content.

Either drop the `UITableView`(are you sure you can't use a `ListView`(which would probably kill all performance problems/exceptions)), modify and improve it so it doesn't add so many levels in the layout or you keep it and modify the rest of the layout to be more efficient.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the answer. The reason I used this tool is that it did the rounding for me, as well as giving me the option to add EditText to a row if I require. I suppose I will have to use GridView or ListView instead, will just take me a week or two to work on getting it just right. Thanks for your input!!

Comment: @AdamM Again I took a really quick look at the library's code. But you could potentially make the `UITableView` lose one layout level by using the `merge` tag in the `list_container.xml` file instead of the *viewsContainer* `LinearLayout` and moving all of its attributes directly to the `UITableView` which extends `LinearLayout`. However I don't know if this works with the rest of the library but it may worth a shot.

Comment: Will have a look at that, however the other issue with the library as you mentioned is performance, its not too bad with a few rows, but if you pull back a large amount of data say 30+ rows, it can be quite slow even on newer devices. Will try using the merge tag to see if that helps any, but I have feeling even if this does resolve the stackoverflow error, it will probably not do too much for the performance issues. Thanks for your time and effort!! Much appreciated

Comment: @AdamM *if you pull back a large amount of data say 30+ rows* - when you have this kind of doubts you use a `ListView` :)

Comment: Yeah it just makes other functions I require from the app more difficult with ListView, but sadly I don't have much choice, ah well, thats the fun of programming I guess